# Laptop Begins to Ground ⏚ after Booting Up

Tags: laptop, audio, power-supply, headphones, ground

Even though my switch board socket as well as my charging laptop adapter supports 3 pin Earthing/Grounding.

Whenever I begin to hot boot my laptop either from Shut-Down-state/Stand-By/Sleep/Hibernate Mode while leaving behind my charger adapter connecting to power socket before/after my laptop battery gets completely backed up with charge. Suddenly Grounding/Earthing(⏚) Symbol appears in my Electricity Meter indicator.

But the vice versa is not true. i.e., whenever I completely switch Shut-Down/Stand-By/Sleep/Hibernate Mode, leaving behind my charger adapter connecting to power socket Grounding/Earthing(⏚) Symbol disappears in my Electricity Meter indicator

Couple of days when an head phone is connected, even though I could hear the audio from my ear phone. But audio from the laptop doesn't get automatically muted after connecting the head phone.

What is the reason behind this? How do I need to solve this?

Comment: It appears you have a ground loop caused by another device besides your laptop and its OEM charging adapter. Can you draw a picture of your set up, scan it, and edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a faulty laptop power adapter. Does the charger have any frayed wires near the plug. The old apple magsafe connectors were notorious for this. The charger wire can cause current to leak to ground and cause this problem.